# Will my Ubuntu One data be removed completely with the impending shutdown?

Tags: ubuntu-one

It's been announced that Ubuntu One cloud backup service will be shut down soon. The announcement offers an app that helps download the backup data before the service finally gets buried.

Downloading data or not, does it have to be explicitly deleted by the owner (by me, for instance)? Or is it contract-guaranteed by the provider (Ubuntu One) to be completely removed from the cloud after the deadline as announced?

Answer (score 12):

Quote from [their website](https://one.ubuntu.com/shutdown/):

> You have until 31 July 2014 to collect all of your content. After that
>   date, all remaining content will be deleted.

So your data will be deleted.

Comment: I would not infer from this, that the drive would be wiped before recycling.  If you really don't want your data in the hands of an unknown, you would be advised to overwrite it.  However, that might not mean what you think on a "cloud" drive and would be dependent on what they used as a storage mechanism.

Comment: @Mark0978 The data is not stored on some hard disk that's going to be sent off to recycling. It's stored in Amazon S3. And it's already on the Internet. If you were worried about your data being in the hands of the unknown, you should have never put it on the Internet.

Answer (score 6):

It will be deleted, yes. It is currently stored in Amazon's S3 service, and on July 31st we will trigger deleting all the data from the S3 bucket. Canonical will no longer have access to the data.
From then on, it follows Amazon's standard processes to delete that data within their infrastructure.